# Alexa skills failure LAMBDA - There was a problem with the requested skill's response

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

I am playing with alexa skill and I keep on getting the "there was a problem with the requested skill's response."

Here's my basic lambda skill

```js
"use strict";

// Include the Alexa SDK
var Alexa = require("alexa-sdk");

// The handlers object tells Alexa how to handle various actions
var handlers = {
    
    "LaunchRequest": function () {
      this.emit(":tell", "Launching HelloWorld"); 
    },
    "WelcomeIntent": function () {
      this.emit(":tell", "Welcome Intent calling");
    }
};


// This is the function that AWS Lambda calls every time Alexa uses your skill.
exports.handler = function(event, context, callback) {

    var alexa = Alexa.handler(event, context);

  
    alexa.registerHandlers(handlers);
    alexa.execute();
};
```

Here's the log from the test

```js
{
 "version": "1.0",
 "session": {
  "new": true,
  "sessionId": "amzn1.echo-api.session.4e78e426-cc1f-41ac-a820-34969b5b4a84",
  "application": {
   "applicationId": "amzn1.ask.skill.750c0348-2471-4f06-801d-c87b3765b3c5"
  },
  "user": ...
 },
 "context": {
  "System": {
   "application": {
    "applicationId": ...
   },
   "user": ...,
   "device": ...,
   "apiEndpoint": "https://api.amazonalexa.com",
   "apiAccessToken": ...
  }
 },
 "request": {
  "type": "LaunchRequest",
  "requestId": "amzn1.echo-api.request.da1c2415-5f32-405e-8642-690f67285561",
  "timestamp": "2018-09-01T21:13:32Z",
  "locale": "en-US",
  "shouldLinkResultBeReturned": false
 }
}
```

Is there any setting I missed? I am only doing the inline coding.

Comment: Put a log and please share the response JSON generated, especially when you get this error.

Comment: I am not getting the JSON output at all. What could be missing?

Answer (score 0):

Use `ask-sdk` instead. Latest v2 has different implementation of SDK and will be better for future support.

Follow the steps in here. Once setup you can create and modify intent handler's according to your need:

https://ask-sdk-for-nodejs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Setting-Up-The-ASK-SDK.html#installing-standard-ask-sdk-distribution

Comment: Thanks for your response @Akshay. Seems like the instruction you sent is for uploading a zip file. What I am trying to do is an inline-coding only. I did replace it to ask-sdk and ask-sdk-core and skip the zip uploading - and it didn't work.